# Cabal ignores --extra-lib-dirs option in clang invocation

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install the `byteable` package on OS X, but Cabal fails with the error `ld: library not found for -lgmp`. I do in fact have libgmp installed, but in a nonstandard location, in `LOCATION=$HOME/homebrew/lib`. (i.e. `$LOCATION/libgmp.dylib` exists).

I tried using the `extra-lib-dirs` option, both in my Cabal .config file and also in the command line invocation (i.e. `cabal install --extra-lib-dirs="$LOCATION" byteable`), but I get the same linker error. When I use the verbose option (`--verbose=3`), I can see that the call to clang in fact does *not* include the `$LOCATION` directory in the `-L` options.

What do I have to do to get cabal to search additional library directories during package installation?

Comment: The flag is extra-lib-*dirs*. You point it to the directory containing the library, not the library itself.

Comment: sorry, that was unclear - I am actually specifying the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not a great solution, but you can add the location of your `libgmp` to the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable when you execute `cabal install`.

In your case, something like:

`LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/homebrew/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH cabal install <package>`

Or, for the standard Homebrew location:

`LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH cabal install <package>`

Unfortunately, while I can find documentation on `LIBRARY_PATH` for gcc, I can't find anything that describes its use for clang. However, the above solution Works For Me (TM) and I **am** running clang.

This seems to be something that has broken with Yosemite. I had no problem with `cabal install` for the Yosemite **Beta**, which I ran for several months. However, when I did a **fresh install** of Yosemite, I had the same problem you describe, with clang unable to find `libgmp`.

Comment: Ugh, I thought I had already tried using that flag, but apparently not. I was actually using 10.9, not 10.10.

Comment: And for some reason cabal *also* started respecting the --extra-lib-dirs option. I really have no idea what changed. But your answer does work for me.